# Symbol on the hightest point of an irregular time series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

is there a way to display a symbol on a specific point (for example on the hightest value) of a time serie (irregular intervals) ?

The code to have a symbol on the hightest point of a 'normal' serie :

```
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
   y: 26.5,
    marker: {
     symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
    }
 }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

My time serie with irregulat interval :

```
 data: [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 10), 5],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 20), 15],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 50), 10],
    ...
```

I looking for a solution to have a symbol on the second value ie 15
I tried `y: Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 20), 15]` and some others 'mix' but it doesn't work ...
Thanks in advance

Comment: this: "[Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 20), 15]" is both your x and y value.  'Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 20)' is the x value, the 15 is the y value, so you need to specify both separately in your point object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    data: [
        {
            x:Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 10), 
            y:5,
            marker: {
                 symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
            }
        },{
            x:Date.UTC(2013, 3, 14, 00, 20), 
            y:15

        }]
```